# Python - IndexError: list index out of range - I searched but I don't know what I'm looking at

Tags: pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.7

I'm getting the above error when trying to web scrape

```
data = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'DataletData'})
data2 = soup.find_all('td', attrs={'class':'DataletData'})
info4 = data[8]
info11 = data2[6]
```

`<td valign="top" align="right" bgcolor="#ffffff" nowrap="" class="DataletData">$159,900</td>` info4 grabs the $159,900

but info11 is showing `<td valign="top" align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" nowrap="" class="DataletData"></td>` but instead of grabbing nothing it gives me this error.

How would I continue with the script if there is nothing to grab?

Thank you in advance for your help.  I'm just getting started and I'm really having fun so far.

Edit:  Full Code - https://github.com/richmccormick87/first/blob/master/scrapingfirsttry.py

My end goal is to be able to upload csv file with names of streets and have the code grab certain data fields and then save the grabbed data to a new csv file. I know I'm a long way from there but I just started coding this morning and this is the first time I've been stopped after searching here

Comment: A little bit more info could be great to know what you are doing.
The fact is if you try to read a non-existing index in a list it will give you this error. That's normal you can not access a non existing index.

Comment: Here is a link to the full code - https://github.com/richmccormick87/first/blob/master/scrapingfirsttry.py

Comment: My end goal is to be able to upload csv file with names of streets and have the code grab certain data fields and then save the grabbed data to a new csv file.  I know I'm a long way from there but I just started coding this morning and this is the first time I've been stopped after searching here.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I continue with the script if there is nothing to grab?

I guess you could modify the script and check if the list is `None` and the list size. If it is not `None` and having expected length, then you will continue to inspect the value of a given index. For example,

```
if data is not None and len(data) >= 8:
  print(data[8]);
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  Unfortunately this still gives me the error.